# Expand table content for each specific sheet in an excel document in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have this structure in Power Query:
[image: structure]

In the ExcelData column there are Excel files, where each file have a sheet named "Pivot Data" that I want to open (for each Table in the ExcelData column). How can I achieve this?

Clicking on the first table I get to this View:
[image: Excel View]

And the content I want to expand for each Excel file is the Table in the Data column.

My power query code:

```
let
    Source = CategoryAssignmentFolder,
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Content"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "ExcelData", each Excel.Workbook(Binary.Buffer([Content]), true))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
let Source = CategoryAssignmentFolder,
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Content"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "ExcelData", each Excel.Workbook(Binary.Buffer([Content]), true)
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom" , "ExcelData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Expanded GetFileData"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded GetFileData", "Data", List,List)
in #"Expanded Data"
```

to generically combine all tabs on all files in a directory:

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\subdirectory\directory"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded GetFileData",{"Content", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind"}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data", List,List)
in  #"Expanded Data"
```

Comment: Hi, I run into this error when running the script: Expression.Error: The name 'Removed Columns' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.

Do you think it would be possible to explain a bit what is going on? So I can learn for the next time :)

Comment: Hi, please provide some comments about what the code does and I can test it out!

Comment: Have an upvote @horseyride as the solution looks perfect to me and it is the least thanks that can be given.

Comment: I'm not saying the solution does not work. I'm pointing out the lack of comments in the code, which does not help others with similar problems identify if the solution is helpful also to them. I'm very grateful you took the time to write the code @horseyride. Maybe this link can help explain what I mean: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421669/how-can-i-answer-a-question-well-on-stack-overflow#:~:text=Please%20be%20sure%20to%20answer%20the%20question.%20Provide,back%20them%20up%20with%20references%20or%20personal%20experience.

Comment: Frankly the code is doing nothing special. Each row is simple in and of itself. If you load and run the code, then click on each step one-by-one you can immediately see what each step is dong. There are no compound secrets that merit me going back and providing row by row commentary of each action.  If there were huge formulas, recursive code or some such, I can see the reason for the request. Here, not so much

Comment: Fair enough, simple it is. But I assume you have lots of experience and forget how even "simple" things can be obstacles before you know them, where comments of what's going on can help a lot. But I accept the answer and leave it at that.

Comment: The commentary on my part would be mostly unhelpful as it would reference the person back to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/power-query-m-function-reference for each function used.  The "trick" is knowing what to do, not how to do it once that is decided